# акселлерометр Unity, чувствительность и выход за лимит

Tags: android, c#, unity3d

Использую следующий код, чтобы получить показания акселлерометра и зафиксировать их максимум.

```
    if (Input.acceleration.y > accelY) { accelY = Input.acceleration.y; }
    if (Input.acceleration.x > accelX) { accelX = Input.acceleration.x; }
    if (Input.acceleration.z > accelZ) { accelZ = Input.acceleration.z; }

    accelYText.text = "Y = " + accelY.ToString();
    accelZText.text = "Z = " + accelZ.ToString();
    accelXText.text = "X = " + accelX.ToString();
```

Проблема в следующем - на разных телефонах есть некий лимит акселлерометра, допустим на моем это 1.90035 по оси х, 2.00055 по оси У и 1.8375 по оси Z. Больше этого значения оно не поднимается.  На другом телефоне эти значения тоже около 2, хотя немного отличаются.

Вроде как бы и понятно все, лимит и лимит, но ребята из SmartTools со своим приложением Vibration Meter(не реклама, просто как образец для того, чтобы понять что я хочу) сумели каким то образом настроить чувствительность акселлерометра и мерить большие значения.

Для примера - максимум по их шкале около 13 баллов, но достичь их практически нереально - телефон надо просто бить об стену, чтобы вышло значение больше 11.

А когда меряешь в юнити, то лимит достигается довольно быстро - стукнул телефоном пару раз об подушку и вот они, цифры, выше которых значение не выдает акселлерометр.

Я понимаю что Vibration Meter написан не на Unity, он весит около 7 мб.

Но всё таки интересно - высокая чувствительность акселлерометра и его быстрое достижение максимума - это недоработка юнити, а в оригинальном андроиде всё ок, или есть какой то хитрый способ и в юне понизить чувствительность акселлерометра?

Всё проверялось и писалось под андроид.
Возможно как то хелпер-классами android unity получится.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Вы путаете величины.**

Акселерометр измеряет ускорение.

А Vibration Meter колебания, там используют датчики, но информацию с них обрабатывают, получают интенсивность колебаний и приводят к какой-то из бальных шкал магнитуды землетрясений.

---

Сделал приложение через AndroidStudio напрямую беру показания с акселерометра. Получаю ускорение в м/с^2. Причем:

```
sensor.getMaximumRange())
```

Возвращает на моем телефоне 32. Это значит, что мой датчик не способен зафиксировать более чем 32м/с^2. Но опытным путем доказано, что максимум ~19.5 м/с^2, больше не фиксирует.

Еще одно замечание, в покое никогда не будет 0. Потому что действует ускорение свободного падения. Следовательно на одном из датчиков будет постоянная **g**, ее значение определенно как константа:

```
SensorManager.STANDARD_GRAVITY;
```

Следовательно ее в расчетах необходимо учитывать.

---

**Аппаратные ограничения**

Человек может придать своей руке ускорение 5g (50м/с^2) и более. А в телефонах предел измерения акселерометров меньше. Выходит проблема с быстрым достижением 
максимума не в Unity или Android, а в аппаратной части, достигнут лимит.
Попробуйте измерять насколько меняется ускорение

```
vibration = Math.Abs(previousAccel-Accel)
```

---

**Получение рывка**

Рывок - векторная физическая величина, характеризующая темп (скорость) изменения ускорения тела. Является третьей производной по времени от радиус-вектора.

В примере рассмотрим получение xy части рывка.

Пример на java, выполнять нужно с фиксированным шагом (`fixedUpdate()` если юнити):

```
xyAccelPrev = xyAccel;//запоминаем ускорение по XY
xyAccel = event.values[0]; //получаем ускорение по XY
xyJerk = Math.abs(xyAccel-xyAccelPrev)/4; //получаем рывок по XY где 4 переводной коэфф
if(xyJerk > xyJerkMax)
    xyJerkMax = xyJerk; //фиксируем максимальный рывок по XY
xyAverageJerk = (xyAverageJerk+xyJerk)/2; //считаем среднее значение по XY
```

Вместо 4 можно поставить любое число, изменится диапазон значений.

для других осей аналогичный код. Вычислив по всем трем осям можно свести к вектору и получать его длину. Будет еще сложнее достичь максимального значения.

Чтобы поддерживать максимальное значение (9,75 на моем телефоне) нужно очень быстро перемещать из стороны в сторону, что достаточно сложно, получилось примерно как в Vibration Meter

---

**Получение длины вектора ускорений**

Вот как можно расширить диапазон измерения в 1.73, в т.ч. выше предела датчика.
Для ускорений, псевдокод:

```
xyAccel//ускорение по xy
xzAccel//ускорение по xz
zyAccel//ускорение по zy
Accel=sqrt(xyAccel^2+xzAccel^2+zyAccel^2)
```

Максимум получится достичь, если придать макс ускорение одновременно по всем осям. Аналогично вычисляется и для вектора рывка.

Comment: Не могли бы вы точнее сказать, что вы имеете ввиду в последнем абзаце? Как померить два ускорения между собой? И как это увеличит range? 
Каким образом при таком аппаратном ограничении можно измерить большие величины?

Comment: ускорение вы большее, чем возможно не измерите. Я предложил мерить скорость изменения ускорения (рывок). Т.е. чтобы его получить необходимо из текущего ускорения вычесть предыдущее ускорение, которое было в прошлом fixedUpdate().

Comment: Если хочется еще менее достижимой цифры, то можно добавить еще и частоту изменений ускорения.

Comment: Можете это расписать кодом? Как получить предыдущее значения FixedUpdate? Вносить их все в лист, стирать последнее и добавлять новое при каждом FixedUpdate? И сравнивать между ними? А если последние два значения будут просто на лимите акселлерометра, то как это решит проблему? Пожалуйста, добавьте просто в ответ полное описание.

Comment: Всегда удивлялся псевдокоду. Добавил типы переменных, точки с запятыми, и получаешь вполне рабочий кусок кода на большинстве языков.